# Criteria API: find the first value in the field

Tags: java, postgresql, criteria, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I have a column in the table where each field can have multiple values.

As an example, I have the following values in the table:

```
id | code 
---|-----------------
 1 |a, c, bc, ac1
 2 |ds, d, cda, aw2
 3 | a1, d, ccdd
```

What I'd like to get as a result is the same table but sorted in ascending order by the first value in each 'code' column:

```
id | code 
---|-----------------
 1 |a, c, bc, ac1
 3 | a1, d, ccdd
 2 |ds, d, cda, aw2
```

I need to take the first value from that column and then sort the table according to that first value.
Is there any way I can achieve this using Criteria API?
I currently use the min value in the field but would like to sort by the first value instead.

```
Expression aggregateFuncExpr = cb.min(sortFieldExpression);

selectionList.add(aggregateFuncExpr);
cb.groupBy(cb.literal(1));

orderList.add(cb.asc(cb.literal(literal)));
```

Comment: Please add an example input/output to explain what you want to do. Show table and column names with values. _I have a column in the table where each field can have multiple values_ a column has values separated by comma or something else.

Comment: Hi, @Eklavya, provided the expected result in the question description. Thanks for taking a look

Comment: Which database you are using and  what is the type for column `code` ?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL, and the type for 'code' is varchar(255)

Comment: You can use `ORDER  BY substring(code, '^(.+?),')` in PostgreSQL to order

Comment: thanks for your help!